# Possible way to detect sim card detection in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, core-telephony

I have a iphone app that has the capability to send messages. I want to alert user when sim card is not available in iphone. So i tried below three function to check sim card availabilty

```
Class messageClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));
if([messageClass canSendText]){
    // Sim available
    NSLog(@"Sim available");
}
else{
    //Sim not available
    NSLog(@"Sim not available");
}

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){
    // Sim available
    NSLog(@"Sim available");
}
else{
    //Sim not available
    NSLog(@"Sim not available");
}

if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456"]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Sim available");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Sim not available");
    }
}
```

I have checked my iphone without sim, it always return @"Sim available". But when i open default "Messages" app and try to send sms it says alert "No SIM Card Installed"... How this message app can detect sim card availabilty?

Comment: I don't think you can, Apple does not expose any information regarding the sim, the cell radio, the network you are on, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the below code you can get the sim card details like carriername,mobilecountrycode,isocountrycode,mobilenetworkcode.In the ios 6 all are retained.So if your sim card is removed also it will retain the old details.So there this idea wont be useful but in ios 7 only carriername is retained and remaining are changed so the below code can be used

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo* info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier* carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;
NSString *mobileCountryCode = carrier.mobileCountryCode;
NSString *carrierName = carrier.carrierName;
NSString *isoCountryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
NSString *mobileNetworkCode = carrier.mobileNetworkCode

// Try this to track CTCarrier changes 
info.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = ^(CTCarrier* inCTCarrier) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"User did change SIM");
        });
};
```

Comment: No as far as i know there is no way to detect the sim card is presence in ios in this method ? But the code you have used also should work fine . I dont know why it didnt work well?

Comment: Apple's default "Message" application detect sim card availability....How that app works well? .

Comment: What is mean by Message application mean?

Comment: No. But i think it is not possible. This application has defaultly installed in iphone right. How can we get that source code? So there is more default apps in iphone like safari , appstore, maps,etc...

Comment: I have found an undocumented method for detecting sim card availability in iphone    .NSString * CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();
int CTGetSignalStrength();

NSString *status = CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();

NSLog(@"Sim card status %@",status);

Comment: yeah this method working fine. But this is undocumented api method, so if i can use this method apple will reject my app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769346/possible-way-to-detect-sim-card-detection-in-ios/24367325#24367325

Comment: How to get both sim details for eSim and physical sim?

Answer (score 10):

You can check it by CTCarrier class.

[image]

```
BOOL isSimCardAvailable = YES;

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo* info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier* carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;

if(carrier.mobileNetworkCode == nil || [carrier.mobileNetworkCode isEqualToString:@""])
{
    isSimCardAvailable = NO;
}
```

You need to add CoreTelephony framework for using CTTelephonyNetworkInfo and CTCarrier.

Answer (score 6):

Implemented in Swift as a read-only computed property:

```
import CoreTelephony

var availableSIM: Bool {
    return CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider?.mobileNetworkCode != nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementing to Anneq and Felipe answers:

**Swift 2.3:**

```
import CoreTelephony
func isSimAvailable()  -> Bool {
    let info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    let carr = info.subscriberCellularProvider
    guard let carrier = carr else {
        return false
    }
    guard let carrierCode = carrier.mobileNetworkCode else {
        return false
    }
    guard carrierCode != "" else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the Anneq Anwar answer, here the swift version:

```
import CoreTelephony
func isSimAvailable()  -> Bool {
    var isSimCardAvailable = true
    var info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    var carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider
    if carrier != nil && carrier.mobileNetworkCode == nil || carrier.mobileNetworkCode.isEqual("") {
        isSimCardAvailable = false
    }
    return isSimCardAvailable
}
```

---

fix: The carrier can be nil in some devices

Comment: Hey Leonardo, seems that depending on the device, the carrier can be nil, thanks man ;D

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4+**

```
var isSimCardAvailable: Bool {

    let info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    if let carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider {
        if let code = carrier.mobileNetworkCode {
            if !code.isEmpty {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+ solution that covers regular SIM and eSIM

```
    func hasCellularCoverage() -> Bool {
        let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

        guard let serviceSubscriberCellularProviders = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders else { return false }
        let carriers = serviceSubscriberCellularProviders.values

        let validCarriers = carriers.compactMap() {
            $0.isoCountryCode
        }

        return !validCarriers.isEmpty ? true : false
    }
```