# Sim card change detection in iOS

Tags: ios, networking, carrier

Somebody please help with the code for sim card detection change in iOS on Swift.

We have an app that lets users authenticate with phone number and we want to detect when user changes his sim(if app is in background) and show alert  asking if he wants to authenticate with new number. Basically we want to detect the carrier change of the phone.

In my Appdelegate (DidFinishLaunching method):-

```
    let info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    if let cellularProvider  = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            print("Notify sim change")

        })
    }
```

This is not detecting sim card change. What am I doing wrong? Please guide.

Thanks In Advance,

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769346/possible-way-to-detect-sim-card-detection-in-ios

Comment: Hi Sudheer, i have already tried it, it doesn't show the code in swift for subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier.

Comment: import CoreTelephony
var availableSIM : Bool {
    if let cellularProvider  = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider {
        if let mnCode = cellularProvider.mobileNetworkCode {
            println(mnCode)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Sudheer. But the code you give checks whether sim is available in phone or not. What we need is to get notified in the app when user changes his sim. So that next time user opens the app show a page asking to user "Do you want to use new number or continue with old number?".

Comment: Hello, does anybody has the answer on how to register for sim change notification in swift?

Comment: have the same question, got any answer for this ?

Comment: Above code is working, when you change the sim while the app is running.

Comment: I want it to work when the app is in background too. Have any option?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In app terminate: check APNS devicetoken. If simcard changes then devicetoken changes too. Check with before devicetoken.
When as app is running: Use `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier`.