# SWIFT: How I can use subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I want use subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier in Swift, but I don't know how and where it can be placed.
Any ideas? I have searched for that, but only Objective-C samples are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective C you just need to use "set" and the name of the property block while in **Swift** you need to assign it:

```
// Declare your class member
let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo();

// In viewDidLoad or in your custom method
networkInfo.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = { carrier in
    // Do whatever you wanna do when a callback comes        
}
```

*carrier* will be of type `CTCarrier`.

Of course, you can always use the $0 which refers to `CTCarrier` argument:

```
networkInfo.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = { 
 $0      
 // Do whatever you need to do with it
}
```

and it looks a lot more cleaner.

Comment: Where to implement this? Appdelegate or any other VC will do?

Comment: You can implement it in each of them

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't test it but this is the code from this answer: [Possible way to detect sim card detection in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769346/possible-way-to-detect-sim-card-detection-in-ios)
translated to swift:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    print("init");

    let info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    info.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = self.cellularProviderDidUpdate
}
func cellularProviderDidUpdate(inCTCarrier: CTCarrier) {
    print("event")
}
```

Don't forget `import CoreTelephony`